# tests for spring boot application are not run

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-test, junit5

I am trying to write an integration for Spring Boot application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.lapots.tree.model.web" })
public class TreeModelApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TreeModelApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() throws Exception {
        ServletRegistrationBean registrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean(new RootServlet(), "/tree-model-app");
        registrationBean.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        registrationBean.setAsyncSupported(true);
        return registrationBean;
    }
}
```

The test looks like this

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT,
        classes = TreeModelApplication.class)
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class TreeModelApplicationIntegrationTest {
    private static final String PING_URL = "http://localhost:8080/tree-model-app/ping";

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    @Test
    public void routerReturnsTrueOnPing() {
        String response = restTemplate.getForObject(PING_URL, String.class);
        assertEquals("false", response, "Ping response should be the same as expected.");
    }
}
```

However when I run `gradlew test` - nothing happens - build successful and reports are empty. What is the problem?

My `build.gradle` is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "https://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty')

    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile("org.springframework:spring-test")
    testCompile("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-runner:$junitPlatformVersion")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:$junitJupiterVersion")
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:$junitJupiterVersion")
    testCompile("com.github.sbrannen:spring-test-junit5:1.0.0.M4")
}
```

Comment: Is it correct the @Test import? I was expecting to see org.junit.Test. Looks like spring is not finding any tests

Comment: Well I am using `Junit5` so I used it

Comment: can u run the tests individually? I mean from the IDE

Comment: @pvpkiran get error `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.platform.engine.discovery.DiscoverySelectors.selectNames(Ljava/util/Collection;)Ljava/util/List;`

Comment: Basically it is `no tests were found`

Comment: Can you also add more from you build.gradle?

Comment: I mean - do you have the gradle jUnit5 plugin set?  
  
apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'

Comment: I need that plugin?

Comment: @Kotse indeed, when I added plugin It started to run `spring boot` and even failed on `DataSourceBeanCreationException` (no idea why though)

Comment: Great, so tests are OK.

Comment: @Kotse, Indeed. Thanks

Comment: DataSourceBeanCreationException - something with db configuration. Looking at your gradle conf - you need another jar at runtime for your DB. For example for postgresql it could be this: runtime ("org.postgresql:postgresql:9.4-1201-jdbc41")

Comment: @Kotse nah, I just needed to remove `boot-jpa` because I don't use database at all for now

Comment: Glad it all works now. If you have time, can you please accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue is gradle plugin was not set up to run jUnit 5 tests

Here the conf needed pasted directly [from JUnit5 website](http://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-build) :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        // The following is only necessary if you want to use SNAPSHOT releases.
        // maven { url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-M4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
```

Comment: 'org.junit.platform.junit-platform-gradle-plugin' is marked as deprecated https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.platform/junit-platform-gradle-plugin. So, this answer is probably not correct for last versons of junit and gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` to the test class declaration

Comment: this is jUnit5, Runner is replaced with @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)